# How do I rank several books in a bookstore based on user votes?

Tags: algorithms

I am currently redesigning an online bookstore where the rating of the books are stored as shown in the table,

```
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| title   | no of votes | average score  |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 1  | 12494       | 3.5            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 2  | 22184       | 4.0            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 3  | 457         | 4.5            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 4  | 7           | 4.5            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 5  | 57          | 4.0            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 6  | 975         | 3.0            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 7  | 3853        | 3.5            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 8  | 4561        | 4.0            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 9  | 24211       | 3.0            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| book 10 | 1           | 5.0            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

The users vote on a scale of `5 stars` for each book, the average score is the simple average of the voted score to the number of voters

how do I rank the books such a way that books with lesser vote counts (`book 10`, `book 4` here) won't get high ranks based on their scores, but the ones with considerably large vote count and high scores.

thanks.

Comment: As a personal note, I prefer to be told both the score and the number of votes.  I often know in advance that I'm looking at an obscure book and I just want to know of those few who have read it liked it or not.  If you need a single ranking system, my inclination would be to cut out all the books with a  small number of votes.  As you suggest, it's hard to compare an option with $25,000$ votes to one with a single vote.

Answer (score 2):

You could adjust the average score by a penalty inversely proportional to the number of votes, e.g., sort by $s-\frac{10}{n+1}$ if the average score is $s$ from $n$ votes. This would push book 5 down to about $3.8$, and already be unnoticable (with one digit precision) for book $3$. But book 4 would be sorted like having a score of just slightly above $3$ and book 10 like a $0$.

A higher numerator than the $10$ I picked would penalize more low-impact books while increasing the risk of medium-impact books being penalized noticably.